# How to hide Lightning Design System Grid item when screen is Small (>= 480px)

Tags: lightning-design-system, slds-grid

I have a Grid which has three columns:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_4-of-12">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_4-of-12">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_4-of-12">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want column 3 to disappear when viewed on a small screen (i.e. mobile device).

How would I achieve that using Salesforce Lightning Design System?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a token for this, which also means modifying your code slightly.

## CSS

```
@media t(mqSmall) {
    .THIS .nonEssential {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

## cmp

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
  <div class="slds-col slds-small-size_6-of-12 slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_4-of-12">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-col slds-small-size_6-of-12 slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_4-of-12">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-col nonEssential slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_4-of-12">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## defaultTokens.tokens

```
<aura:tokens extends="force:base">

</aura:tokens>
```

## defaultTokens.tokens-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AuraDefinitionBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>41.0</apiVersion>
    <description>A Lightning Component Bundle</description>
</AuraDefinitionBundle>
```

Comment: Hell, thanks for this answer, I was so confused how to use media query token, its so non intuitive

Comment: @user1974566 The docs don't make it clear. I hope this helps out a lot of people.

Comment: I am unable to deploy using SFDX, I get this error `No TOKENS named markup://c:defaultTokens found`

Comment: @Robs You need to create a defaultTokens.tokens file. You can do this in the Developer Console under (File > New > Lightning Tokens) that includes the default tokens (force:base). This additional edit should help.

Comment: If I create it in VS Code, does it live in the `aura` folder? and does it need a `defaultTokens.tokens-meta.xml` file? do you have example contents for the meta file?

Comment: @Robs Yes, it's called `defaultTokens`, and there will be a meta.xml file as well. It has the same format as other meta.xml files. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks! Just one clarification: does it live in the `aura` folder or a `defaultTokens` folder?

Comment: @Robs yes the files will be in `force-app/main/default/aura/defaultTokens` if you're using default configuration. It appears as a normal component, but has a different type of file from a normal component.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting that SLDS supports [Responsive visibility classes](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/visibility/#Responsive) -

> Responsive visibility classes will hide content on specific
> breakpoints. slds-show_[breakpoint] renders display: none when the the
> view port width is smaller than the breakpoint, and does nothing if it
> is bigger or equal. slds-hide_[breakpoint] does the opposite by
> rendering display: none when the the viewport width is bigger or equal
> than the breakpoint, and does nothing if it is smaller.

Example:

```
<div class="slds-hide_x-small">
    Hidden on screens with more than 320px width
</div>
```